# jQuery datepicker won't work on a AJAX added html element

Tags: html, ajax, jquery

I have a jQuery datepicker function bound to the "birthday" input html element, written in the page header:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $( "#birthday" ).datepicker();
    });
</script>
```

Next, I have some AJAX functionality - it adds new input html element to the page. That element is:

```
<input type="text" id="birthday" value="" class="detail-textbox1" />
```

Clicking on that *birthday* element does not pop up the date picker below the text field. I expected this, as the element is added after the page is loaded, thus it isn't in relation with the function provided in the header.

How can I make it work? I tried moving the script from the header to the body, but nothing seems to work. Thanks.

P.S. If I create an input html element with id="birthday" in the page body, everythig works as expected. It appears that only the elements added through AJAX are dysfunctional.

Answer (score 17):

I'm a bit late to the party, but for thoroughness - and with the `.live()` function being [deprecated from jQuery 1.7](http://api.jquery.com/live/) onwards - I thought I'd provide an updated solution based on my experiences, and from all the help I got from other answers on StackOverflow!

I had a situation where I needed to add the `datepicker` functionality to input fields that were being added to the DOM through AJAX calls at random, and I couldn't modify the script making the AJAX calls to attach the `datepicker` functionality, so I opted for the new shiny `.on()` function with its delegation features:

```
// do this once the DOM's available...
$(function(){

    // this line will add an event handler to the selected inputs, both
    // current and future, whenever they are clicked...
    // this is delegation at work, and you can use any containing element
    // you like - I just used the "body" tag for convenience...
    $("body").on("click", ".my_input_element", function(){

        // as an added bonus, if you are afraid of attaching the "datepicker"
        // multiple times, you can check for the "hasDatepicker" class...
        if (!$(this).hasClass("hasDatepicker"))
        {
            $(this).datepicker();
            $(this).datepicker("show");
        }
    });
});
```

I hope this helps someone, and thanks for all the answers so far that led me to this solution that worked for me! :)

Comment: I don't have a choice but to use jquery 1.7 because it's a requirement at work.  :'(.    But, the jQuery 1.7 version of what you're showing above doesn't work for me.  :/.  So, frustrating.

Comment: @user919860 - The function is deprecated, not removed, so you are still able to use the `live()` function in 1.7 as far as I know...the documentation on the jQuery website concerning the `live()` function is really good, and you can [check it out here](http://api.jquery.com/live/). They also recommend using the `delegate()` function for use with older versions of jQuery, and the details for that function are on the same page in the documentation, but please shout if you're still struggling! :)

Answer (score 4):

You need to use .live() so that any newly added elements have the event handler attached: http://api.jquery.com/live/

```
$('#birthday').bind('load', function() {
    $(this).datepicker();
});
```

**EDIT**

[.live() documentation](http://api.jquery.com/live/) states, that it is a bit out of date. With new versions of jquery (1.7+) use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Comment: Thanks JK. Using .live() solves the issue. Instead of your example, I used $('#birthday').live('focus', function() { $(this).datepicker(); });

Comment: @Boris the .datepicker() function creates the picker, so you only need to call it once. But it won't really hurt too much I guess to do it every time on focus (but it is less efficient than it could be).

Comment: if I change 'focus' to 'load' it doesn't work at all. Also, I've noticed that when I tab in the datepicker and tab out (without choosing any value), none of my AJAX/php scripts work. ?!?! What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Boris, JK: This was super helpful for me. I have also found that you can use the following for AJAX html if you want to use Datepicker's date range selection:

```
$('#groundtransporation').live('focus', function() {
var gt = $( "#rentalPickUp, #rentalDropOff" ).datepicker({
  defaultDate: "+1w",
  changeMonth: true,
  numberOfMonths: 2,
  onSelect: function( selectedDate ) {
    var option = this.id == "rentalPickUp" ? "minDate" : "maxDate",
      instance = $( this ).data( "datepicker" ),
      date = $.datepicker.parseDate(
        instance.settings.dateFormat ||
        $.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat,
        selectedDate, instance.settings );
    gt.not( this ).datepicker( "option", option, date );
  }
});
});
```

Comment: Point to note here is live method binds for elements currently on the page, as well as ones created later on, thus solving the problem of elements being added later not having the DtPicker. However, live method is now deprecated in favor of 'on'

Answer (score 1):

I got another case. 
My script is copying last table elements including datepicker.

The jquery will not working because the copied element has mark that it "hasDatepicker".

To activate datepicker in new element, remove that class name and the initiate it, like this.

$("#yournewelementid").attr("class","your-class-name"); 
 $("#yournewelementid").datepicker();

Answer (score 1):

your issue is always happens when elements don't exist when you try to initialize it.
When you use **$(function(){*/** some code **/*});** elements must exsit on the document, it means that has to be on the html so you could can create a function to initialize the component or initialize it on the success event after been add it to the document.
Is important to first add the external html load in the ajax request to the document before you try to initialize it or it won't be initialize at all.
Example:

$.ajax({
    
    url:"ajax_html.html",
    
    dataType:"html"
}).done(function(html){

    
$("#selector").html(html)
    
init();
});

function init(){
    
   $(".birthday").datepicker({});
}

Answer (score 0):

You could initialize the date picker for the newly added element within your ajax success callback:

```
 $.ajax({

    ...

    success: function(response) {
        if(response.success) {
              $(body).append(response.html);
              $("#birthday").datepicker();
        }
    }
 });
```