# jQuery datepicker does not work after Ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, datepicker

Here is the situation: I'm using jQuery to dynamically load a form. In that form, there is a datepicker from jQueryUI. The problem is that the datepicker loads the first time, but if the form is loaded again, the datepicker doesn't work. I know I need to rebind the datepicker function each time the page is loaded, but all of my attempts have failed. Any help would be appreciated!

Code snippet below:

```
function makeMyDay() 
{
    $(".datepicker").datepicker(
    {
        inline: true
    });
}

function getNewPage(id,idTwo)
{
    $.ajax(
    {
        type: "GET",
        url: 'foo.php',
        data: "id=" + id,
        success: function(data) 
        {
            $('.bar' + idTwo).html(data);
            makeMyDay();
        }
    });
}
```

Just in case it needs clarifying, foo.php gets loaded into .bar. The datepicker itself is in foo.php, and the external JS files are in the main file, not foo.php.

**Edit**

Updated code below, but the problem still persists:

```
$(function()
{
    $('.datepicker').datepicker({inline: true});
});

function getNewPage(id,idTwo)
{
    $.ajax(
    {
        type: "GET",
        url: 'foo.php',
        data: "id=" + id,
        success: function(data) 
        {
            $('.bar' + idTwo).html(data).find(".datepicker").datepicker(
            {
                inline: true
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: this looks strange `$(makeMyDay);`

Comment: You were right, just fixed it, but the problem remains.

Comment: Maybe you will have to destroy the datepicker before trying to create it again.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you were thinking of? I quickly tried to destroy the datepicker, but it didn't seem to do anything.

Comment: Oops, it's    inline. :)

Comment: Seems to work with `.html()` without destroying http://jsfiddle.net/salman/Vd5Sa/1/ and with destroying http://jsfiddle.net/salman/Vd5Sa/2/

Comment: I am getting the following error: TypeError: $(...).html(...).find(...).datepicker is not a function

Comment: Nevermind, the issue was there were two jQuery file calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switch `$(makeMyDay);` to `makeMyDay();` should do the trick because makeMyDay is a function and not a selector.

Or try to bind the datepicker() directly after the ajax-call as far as .datepicker is in the .bar container this should work:

```
function getNewPage(id,idTwo)
{
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: 'foo.php',
        data: "id=" + id,
        success: function(data) {
             $('.bar' + idTwo).html(data).find(".datepicker").datepicker({
                   inline: true
              });
        }
    });
}
```

A working example that simulates the process can be found here:  http://jsfiddle.net/7wBWB

Comment: That's what I thought was the problem, but unfortunately I just tried your code and the result is the same: the datepicker loads the first time, but fails to load subsequent times.

Comment: Looks strange. Do you get any errors? I will try to create a jsfiddle for that to help you.

Comment: I just tried this process here and it works properly http://jsfiddle.net/7wBWB/ - what is stored in your "idTwo" variable? because that changes your class-selector. Can you provide a part of your html-code?

Comment: I can get datepicker to work if there are multiple instances on the same page, but for some reason it breaks with an Ajax call. In idTwo, it's just a variable from a db query: <div class="bar<?php echo $idtwo;?>">

Comment: The way it's working is I have a foreach loop, each of which carries with it a .bar + (ID). That particular .bar + (ID) loads foo.php with the original "id", which then dynamically loads content from foo.php.

Comment: I get the following error: TypeError: $(...).html(...).find(...).datepicker is not a function

Comment: Turns out it was because I was calling jQuery files twice... doh! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I've been having similar problems this afternoon and solved them, thanks to @Chris Kempen's answer for the idea to test for the hasDatePicker class here: [jQuery datepicker won't work on a AJAX added html element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4812784/jquery-datepicker-wont-work-on-a-ajax-added-html-element)

I used this line to bind using an element that is not updated by the ajax call:

```
$('.container').on('focus', 'input[type=date]', this.bindDatepicker);
```

in this.bindDatepicker, I chose focus instead of his click but used his idea to test for hasClass('hasDatepicker').

I was using Modernizr to test Modernizr.inputtypes.date and then loading the file that binds the datepicker.

Answer (score 0):

Try these code. In my case loading content through ajax it works

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('body').click(function(event) {
   if ($(event.target).is("#new_datepicker")) {
     $("#new_datepicker").datepicker({showOn: 'focus'}).focus();
   }
 });
});
```