# JQuery datepicker not working after ajax call

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I have the following code

```
<html>
    <head>
       //included all jquery related stuff ..not shown here
    </head>
    <body>
       <button id = 'btn' />
       <div id = 'ct'>
             <?php echo file_get_contents('my_ajax_stuff.php'); ?>
       </div>
    </body>
    <script>
       $('.datepicker').datepicker({dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy"});
       $('#btn').click(function() {
           $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "my_ajax_stuff.php" ,
            success: function(response) {
                $('#ct').html(response);
                /*added following line to solve this issue ..but not worked*/
                //$( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy"});

            } ,
            error: function () {
                $('#ct').html("Some problem fetching data.Please try again");
            }
        });
       });
    </script>
</html>
```

The page

> my_ajax_stuff.php

contains a jquery ui datepicker with class = 'datepicker'.On the first load the datepicker works.But when I click on the button to reload it again , the contents are replaced with new contents.But the datepicker is not working.I have tried initialising the datepicker inside the ajax success handler ,as you see.But it also failed.What is the issue.How can it be solved???

Comment: I have tried that,which is commented in ajax success handler here..But no difference

Comment: And what give you in success callback: `$( ".datepicker" ).length` ? Any error in console? BTW, you could use a workaround by reinitialize datepicker when needed (not already done) on mouseenter for example. Mouseenter should be delegated

Comment: .length returns 1.No error in console

Comment: please, provide the HTML code of .datepicker element as it is in `response`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to `reinitialize` the date picker in Ajax success

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker({dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy"});

$('#btn').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "my_ajax_stuff.php" ,
        success: function(response) {

            $('#ct').html(response);
            $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
            /*added following line to solve this issue ..but not worked*/
            //$( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy"});

        } ,
        error: function () {
            $('#ct').html("Some problem fetching data.Please try again");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I've already tried that with
$( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy"});
But not worked

Comment: @JinuJosephDaniel works fine here....http://jsfiddle.net/9rVK4/ something else is wrong in your code

Comment: @charlietfl :That's not the case.I have a datepicker already in the page..and another one is overwriting it..In your case you have no datepicker..and the datepicker is loaded by ajax

Comment: @JinuJosephDaniel here's your scenario working finne also  http://jsfiddle.net/9rVK4/3/

Answer (score 6):

The answer you are looking for may be similar to this question:
[jQuery datepicker won't work on a AJAX added html element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4812784/jquery-datepicker-wont-work-on-a-ajax-added-html-element)

You're replacing the datepicker element in the DOM with the ajax response.
The reason this works for the first time is that PHP renders the my_ajax_stuff.php on first load already in the HTML so it becomes available to jQuery in the DOM.

```
// do this once the DOM's available...
$(function(){

// this line will add an event handler to the selected inputs, both
// current and future, whenever they are clicked...
// this is delegation at work, and you can use any containing element
// you like - I just used the "body" tag for convenience...
    $("body").on("click", ".datepicker", function(){
            $(this).datepicker();
            $(this).datepicker("show");
    });
});
```

Comment: i'd filter it just in case: `$("body").on("click", ".datepicker:not(.hasDatepicker)", function(){...});`

Comment: @JinuJosephDaniel could you just provide HTML markup of .datepicker element as it is in response and as i asked you 10 mins ago???

Comment: @JinuJosephDaniel i don't know, it should work as you have already tried

Comment: Check if you have 'hasDatepicker' class! That was problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

Call your picker inside `.ajaxComplete` function.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // setup picker here...
});

$(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
   // setup picker here...
});
```

Here is a [link](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxcomplete/)

Answer (score 0):

I came across this question because I was having the same problem as OP.

Mooed Farooqui's recommendation to `reinitialize` in Ajax success worked, but not initially.

Ended up that I was also calling the `datepicker` function in my equivalent of `my_ajax_stuff.php`. After I took that out it worked perfectly on button reload and postbacks. Hope this helps someone that stumbles upon this old question...

Answer (score 0):

This may be a primitive solution, but I found that If I have in my main document a function MakeDatePicker and I used it in the OnChange portion of my input, I was able to make any object, ajax, or otherwise, turn into a date picker before, and after an ajax call.
Here is the function and the call. (please note, I have ColdFusion # functions, as this is a return on a coldfusion query with a CFOutput.)

```
<td><input type="date" class="EstDeliveryDatePicker" chassis="#chassis#" value= "#DateFormat(EstDelivery,'mm/dd/yy')#" onclick="MakeDatePicker(this);"></input></td>
```

here is the function at the top of my page:

function MakeDatePicker(obj)
            {
                $(obj).datepicker({
                    changeMonth: true,
                    changeYear: true
                });
                $(obj).datepicker("show");
            }

like I said, its crude, but it works.

I was having an issue with the way my tables would display their sorts. I have it so when you enter the page, you have 1 field that you can click on to select a date. If you click on one of the headers, it would sort SQL command, and re-display the table. This would break the .datepicker function. So I change it to not read off the class, but make the click, trigger the function. the problem with trying to get it to run on the .class was it would initialize after the table was redrawn and lose the scope of the DOM.