# Datepicker in UiTab not appearing

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker, jquery-ui-tabs

I'm trying to get the datepicker popup to appear. I see the text field but when I click on it, nothing happens. If I move the input tag to the top of the page it works. However, in the Jquery UI tab container, I don't see the popup.

Here's the code:

```
<div id="tabs-2" aria-labelledby="ui-id-2" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom" role="tabpanel" aria-expanded="true" aria-hidden="false" style="display: block;" tabcounter="2" symbol="GOOG" exchange="NASDAQ">
 <div class="_container"> 
     <input type="text" id="datepicker_start">
     <span class="favorite" id="star2" status="on" style="display: inline; color: rgb(239, 239, 239);">★</span>
```

Comment: Provide a fiddle to work ?

Comment: You did not even close the divs. Can you please re-post the codes with a clearer descriptions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I figured it out. It doesn't register if the datepicker is added dynamically to the page. For a good explanation and a solution, see the following:

[jQuery datepicker won't work on a AJAX added html element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4812784/jquery-datepicker-wont-work-on-a-ajax-added-html-element)

Thanks to everyone that tried to help :-).