# Jquery datepicker doesnt work on appended element

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I can't seem to get the datepicker to work on this.

My Javascript:

```
$(function () {
    $('.date-picker1').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' }).val();


}
);
```

And this is the function that the button will call once clicked.

```
    var count2 = "1";
function addRow2(in_tbl_name)
{
    var tbody = document.getElementById(in_tbl_name).getElementsByTagName("TBODY")[0];
    // create row
    var row = document.createElement("TR");


    // create table cell 2
    var td2 = document.createElement("TD")
    var strHtml2 = "<input class='date-picker1' name='date"+count2+"' id='date"+count2+"'     />";
    td2.innerHTML = strHtml2.replace(/!count2!/g,count2);

    row.appendChild(td2);

    count2 = parseInt(count2) + 1;
    // append row to table
    tbody.appendChild(row);
}
```

Comment: No it does not, and it never will. You have to initialize the datepicker on the element after it actually exists.

Comment: Can you recreate the issue in http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/oe8d2og1/3/

Comment: The simple structure you have shared can be simplified to - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/oe8d2og1/4/

Comment: I have something like this http://jsfiddle.net/oe8d2og1/7/ After the third date field has been added, it updates back the first date field. The subsequent rows are ok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @adeneo said:

Put:

```
$('.date-picker1').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' }).val();
```

After

```
tbody.appendChild(row);
```

Comment: This somewhat works EXCEPT for the second row.Others rows are fine. Actually, I have another datepicker but with a different class 'date-pickermain'. When I set the date for the second row, that date field is populated instead.

Comment: Read more another way to do that: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4812784/jquery-datepicker-wont-work-on-a-ajax-added-html-element

Comment: I think I know why. ID for date2 is assigned to the other main date element instead. Thanks alot!